# How to remove chrome remote desktop URL forwarder icon from apps

Tags: chromium, remote

I was playing around with Chrome remote desktop, Chromium and at some point, I've installed something named "Chrome Remote Desktop URL Forwarder".
I saw it in the applications, but I can't find any valid way to remove it.

[App Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6OK5.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it something that you installed from Chrome's web store?

Answer (score 1):

You need to purge the Chrome remote desktop package if you want to remove it from your system.

You probably installed it  after you installed that extension on chrome.

Use this command to remove it.

```
sudo apt purge chrome-remote-desktop
```

Comment: I don't see any package with such name in the repositories and yes, I have Google Chrome installed and the Chrome repository.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Same for me I had to install the extension and install the downloaded package to replicate this issue. This package is not installed for every user.

Comment: OK, so where does the package comes from? Extensions are managed by the browsers and if some of those installs packages, those have to be in some repository, I think... Unless they're snaps which isn't the case with Chrome. It is the case with Chromium but if the extension was installed in Chromium then just removing should remove anything related with it and in any case snaps do not install .deb packages.

Comment: @ChanganAuto When you follow the instructions to install the said software from https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/ , it downloads the .deb package for you to install on your machine along with the extension.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes sense, it's provided by Google on demand.